# Why isn't passed into Mockito.when not used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I think there is either a basic misunderstanding on my part with how **when** works, or more specifically how Mockito is working.

I have a service class that has a utility class injected via constructor. The utility class has some other dependencies autowired by constructor as well.

A service class method calls several methods in the utility class. The test uses **when/thenReturn** statements on the called utility methods. When I make a call on the service method, I get an NPE on a utility method  called with a null parameter. But I expected parameters set in the **when** clause to be set. Code below:

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass {
    private Utility utility;
    public ServiceClass(Utility utility) {
        this.utility = utility;
    }

    public serviceMethod(MyDocument myDocument, List<Attachment> attachments) {
        SomeType variable1;
        OtherType variable2;
        List<String> stringList;
        long time;

        time = utility.method1(variable1, variable2);
        stringList = utility.method2(myDocument, attachments.get(0));
...
}

@Service
public class Utility {
    private Dependency1 depend1;
    private Dependency2 depend2;
    public Utility(Dependency1 depend1, Dependency2 depend2) {
        this.depend1 = depend1;
        this.depend2 = depend2;
    }

    public long method1(SomeType var1, OtherType var2) {
    ....
   }

   public List<String> method2(MyDocument myDoc, Attachment attach) {
   ....
   }
```

Now the test code looks as follows:

```
public TestClass {
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @Mock
    private Depend1 depend1;

    @Mock 
    private Depend2 depend2;

    @InjectMocks
    private Utility utility;

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        serviceClass = new ServiceClass(utility);
    }

    @Test
    public testServiceMethod() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MyDocument doc = new MyDocument();
        List<Attachments> attachments = Arrays.asList(new Attachment(...), new Attachment(...));
        SomeType some = new SomeType();
        OtherType other = new OtherType();

        when(utility.method1(some, other)).thenReturn(time);
        when(utility.method2(doc, attachments.get(0)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new String("stg 1"), new String("stg 2"));

        String resp = serviceClass.serviceMethod(doc, attachments);
        assertEquals("service completed", resp);
    }
}
```

But when **utility.method2** is called, *myDocument* shows as null. I was expecting that it would be an instance of MyDocument.

Do I have something misconfigured? Am I missing a concept here? All help appreciated!

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Corrected the arguments to the serviceMethod.

Comment: can you show the error message with stack trace?

Comment: Is there a reason you are mocking the dependencies of Utility instead of just mocking Utility directly?

Comment: Does this even compile? ServiceClass.serviceMethod expects a MyDocument in the first parameter, but you are passing it a SomeType in your test. There is also no return type on ServiceClass.serviceMethod. Get your example compiiling and running and come back

Comment: The `when` is not going to provide an instance of `MyDocument` to the `utility.method2` call.  The `MyDocument` instances is passed in by the caller, correct?

Comment: @Deadpool it's just a Java NPE on the call to utility.method2.

@kingkupps I was under the impression that all of the dependencies would have to be mocked or real.

@MarkOfHall Yes, the MyDocument instance is passed in. I didn't realized that the ```when``` didn't pass in the instance.

Comment: As far as I see `utility` is not a mock, so you  should not (be able to) pass it into the the `Mockito.when` expression.

Comment: The `Utility` isn't a mock and you are trying to register behavior on a non-mock thus it isn't going to work. You need to register behavior on the mocks (the dependencies for `Utility` or make `Utility` a mock instead of mocking its dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

The `ServiceClass` is the class you are testing, so you should anotate with @Mock only the dependencies of this class in your test, in your case the `utility` attribute, remove `Depend1` and `Depend1` declarations. The `setup` method is not necessary, you can anotate `serviceClass` in your test with `@InjectMocks` instead, it take cares of the injections automatically. And finally, your `TestClass` need the `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` to make everything work if it's not there.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class TestClass{
   @InjectMocks
   private ServiceClass serviceClass;

   @Mock
   private Utility utility;
}
```

This is a basic definition for your TestClass, the test itself looks correct, but can be improved to use `ArgumentMatchers` on the "`when`" clause and add a `verify` clause using `ArgumentCaptor` to validate the parameters.